# Laravel: fetch pivot table association

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have several tables:

```
Quote
    id_quote (PK)

ItemQuote
    id_item_quote (PK)
    quote_id (FK)
    item_id (FK)

Item
    item_id (PK)
```

On each **ItemQuote**, there can be several **Service**s:

```
ItemQuoteService
    id_item_quote_service (PK)
    item_quote_id (FK)
    service_id (FK)

Service
    id_service (PK)
```

**Schema:**
[image]

I use two custom pivot entities, because there is other fields in the relation:

```php
class Quote extends Model {
    // ...
    public function items() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class, 'ItemQuote', 'quote_id')
            ->using(ItemQuote::class);
    }
}

class ItemQuote extends Model {
    // ...
    public function services() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class, 'ItemQuoteService', 'id_item_quote')
            ->using(ItemQuoteService::class);
    }
}
```

When I'm getting a **Quote**, I can easily aces **ItemQuote**

```php
$quote = Quote::with([
      'items',
    ])->findOrFail($id);

$quote->items->pivot // contains the attributes of ItemQuote
```

I want to also have access to the attributes of **ItemQuoteService**. But I don't know what to pass to the `with` function to make it work.

```php
$quote = Quote::with([
      'items.pivot.service', // NOT WORKING
    ])->findOrFail($id);
```

How can I acces `Quote->ItemQuote->ItemQuoteService` attributes (from the fetching of one **Quote**) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to retrieve them using an extra relation:

```php
// Class Quote
public function ItemQuoteServices()
{
    return $this-hasManyThrough(ItemQuoteService::class, ItemQuote::class, 'quote_id', 'item_quote_id');
}
```

You then call it using `$quote->with(['itemQuoteServices']);`.

You have to double check those 3rd and 4th parameters, it might just work if you leave them out.

You could also create an `ItemQuoteServices()` on the `Item` class (much the same code), but then you have to call it using `->with(['items', 'items.itemQuoteServices'])`, which retrieves a bit more data.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is there a way to have the list of **ItemQuoteService** inside each item quote instead of "separately" ?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. You can build a relation `$itemQuote->hasMany(ItemQuoteService::class)`